# Apache POI sheet page break

Tags: apache, apache-poi

If I have cell coordinate, can I somehow get sheets next page break coordinate for first cell? I need this for printing purposes, because I'm making rather complex report and I want to copy in last page explanations. Row sizes varies, so I can't depend on fixed row count.